# setController() must be of the type string

Tags: symfony, php-7.4, easyadmin

I have a Back office with EasyAdmin.

I'm using, php 7.4, EasyAdmin 3 and symfony 5.4

The url /admin was redirect like this to my Order:

```
use App\Entity\Header;
use App\Entity\Carrier;
use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Controller\Admin\OrderCrudController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\CrudUrlGenerator;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $routeBuilder = $this->get(CrudUrlGenerator::class);

        return $this->redirect($routeBuilder->setController(OrderCrudController::class)->generateUrl());
    }
```

When I go to my url /admin I have an error:

```
Argument 1 passed to EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\AdminUrlGenerator::setController() must be of the type string
```

In my OrderCrudController I have:

```
    private $entityManager;
    private $crudUrlGenerator;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, CrudUrlGenerator $crudUrlGenerator)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->crudUrlGenerator = $crudUrlGenerator;
    }
```

Do you know why I have this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem.

In my OrderCrudController I need to use:

```
    private $adminUrlGenerator;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, CrudUrlGenerator $crudUrlGenerator, AdminUrlGenerator $adminUrlGenerator)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->crudUrlGenerator = $crudUrlGenerator;
        $this->adminUrlGenerator = $adminUrlGenerator;
    }
```

And I use in my function the url like this:

```
$url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(OrderCrudController::class)
            ->setAction('index')
            ->generateUrl();

        return $this->redirect($url);
    }
```

It's on the documentation: [Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/crud.html)